# RMAN backup copy - read once and write many?

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I am trying to find out what happens in this scenario:

```
BACKUP COPIES 2
```

What actually happens in the `BACKUP COPIES` above?  Does Oracle RMAN read the data files each time for each separate copy?  Or does it read only once and write as many copies as specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you specify `COPIES 2` each block is read once and written two times to backupset copies. The two backupset copies are supposed to be bit-to-bit identical. Both copies have the same backupset key (BS_key) in RMAN. You cannot mix tape and disk copies - either both copies go to `DEVICE DISK` or both to `DEVICE SBT`.